# How to run a Python script in Makefile

Tags: shell, python, make

I want to write a Makefile to find specific files and run a Python script on each file. The Python script accepts `sys.stdin` input.

```
find $(W)/$(OVE) -name "*.xml" -print | \
while read x ; do \
  cat $x | /opt/exp/bin/python2.7 process_results.py > $(W)/$(OVE)/$(dirname $x)_$(basename $x).xml \
done
```

The output is `$(dirname $x)_$(basename $x).xml` file which is an empty _.xml file.

When I run this command on command line, it works properly but in Makefile it doesn't work.

Can you help me what is wrong with this command?

Comment: Also, what is the exact output from your `make` invocation? (You may want to do this in a directory with only one or a few files, to minimize clutter.)

Comment: I want to run a python script on a few xml files in the directory and save the results in a new xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to quote the dollar signs that are supposed to be interpreted by the shell. As it is, `$x` and `$(dirname $x)` and `$(basename $x)` are parsed by make. You're also missing a semicolon at the end of the body of the while loop. Check the output from running make, you should see the shell complaining about that.

```
find $(W)/$(OVE) -name "*.xml" -print | \
while read x ; do \
  cat $$x | /opt/exp/bin/python2.7 process_results.py > $(W)/$(OVE)/$$(dirname $$x)_$$(basename $$x).xml; \
done
```

Another likely problem is that `$(dirname $x)` already contains the `$(W)/$(OVE)` part. For example, if `$(W)` is `foo` and `$(OVE)` is `bar` and `$x` is `subdir/subsubdir/wibble.xml`, you'll end up trying to write files like `foo/bar/foo/bar/subdir/subsubdir_wibble.xml.xml`, whereas you probably mean to write `foo/bar/foo/bar/subdir/subsubdir_wibble.xml.xml`. It's also weird that you're transforming a `.xml` file into a `.xml.xml` file. If you meant to strip the original `.xml` extension, you need to write `basename $$x .xml`, but it's pointless to remove the extension only to add it again. So you probably meant to write:

```
find $(W)/$(OVE) -name "*.xml" -print | \
while read x ; do \
  /opt/exp/bin/python2.7 process_results.py <$$x >$$(dirname $$x)_$$(basename $$x); \
done
```

A further problem is that if any of the runs of `process_results.py` fails, make will continue running and still report a successful build. Tell the shell to stop if an error occurs:

```
set -e; \
find $(W)/$(OVE) -name "*.xml" -print | \
while read x ; do \
  /opt/exp/bin/python2.7 process_results.py <$$x >$$(dirname $$x)_$$(basename $$x); \
done
```

Comment: when I use /opt/exp/bin/python2.7 process_results.py <$$x >$$(dirname $$x)_$$(basename $$x);  the output is an empty file. It seems no input has been passed th the script, the script reads input from stdin. how can I change this line? thanks

Comment: @Hamideh Works for me. Are you sure your script is producing output? Add a trace whenever it reads a line or something.

Answer (score 2):

`$x`, `$(dirname $x)` etc... will all get mangled by make as it interprets them as its own variables. Best to wrap this in a one-line shellscript and call that from the Makefile.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I'm new to scripting and makefile. Can you give me a straight forward guideline. Thanks.

Comment: @Hamideh. What Dennis is suggesting is to get your script to work as a pure bash .sh file first. Then take the additional step of embedding it in the Makefile. I recommend this approach too. 'get it working, then get it right, then get it fast'.

Answer (score 2):

You need to quote the dollar-signs that you want to pass through to the shell, otherwise `make` will try to interpret them.

```
-find $(W)/$(OVE) -name -print | \
  while read x ; do \
      cat $$x | /opt/exp/bin/python2.7 process_results.py \
        > $(W)/$(OVE)/$$(dirname $$x)_$$(basename $$x).xml; \
  done
```

The single dollar-signs are make variable expansions. The double dollar-signs are passed through to the command line as a single dollar-sign.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Camh. But when I use $$x, in this case, even empty _.xml file is not created.